# How to re change sorting of the coming result manually .cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, datalist

Hi I have a code as below and for more detail I am placing an image as below . I want my coming result record be re-change like my 2 and 4 result should be display at last of my product list(DataList).
I am not able to excess the code so need to re-arrange from .cs page. Any idea

```
    ProductList.DataSource = ProductDataSource.NarrowSearch(_Keywords, this.CategoryId, _ManufacturerId, 1, 0, _PageSize, (_HiddenPageIndex * _PageSize), SortResults.SelectedValue);
    ProductList.DataBind();
```

[image]

So I actually want my data to be displayed as `[0], [1], ... [9], [10], [2], [4]`

**Answer resolved as**

```
List<Product> narrowsearch = new List<Product>();
List<Product> narrowsearchstoredata = new List<Product>();
narrowsearchstoredata = ProductDataSource.NarrowSearch(_Keywords, this.CategoryId, _ManufacturerId, 1, 0, _PageSize, (_HiddenPageIndex * _PageSize), SortResults.SelectedValue);
Product item1 = narrowsearchstoredata[0];
Product item2 = narrowsearchstoredata[3];
narrowsearchstoredata.Remove(item1);
narrowsearchstoredata.Remove(item2);
narrowsearchstoredata.Add(item1);
narrowsearchstoredata.Add(item2);
ProductList.DataSource = narrowsearchstoredata;
ProductList.DataBind();
```

Comment: How would use as a human know that?

Comment: @BugFinder need to sort the data as needed and also I am not able to excess the code as it is converted in .dll files

Comment: I can get the data implementing the ADO.net code but there I need to make more changes so post the code here to get easiest way

Comment: thats not what I asked you - I asked how you as a human determine that you want 2 and 4 to come last.  Then you need to apply that to your code

Comment: @BugFinder I do not want to make sort all the data. As per requirement i want to show 2nd and 4th record should shown last of data list and else record should shown as usual, I have to only 11 record which need to be rearrange

Comment: Then your wording is confusing!

Comment: @BugFinder still you are confused?Did you get what i want?

Comment: no.  it is not clear - perhaps thats why only I have made any comments the requirements may make sense to you, but to no one else

Comment: As I understand it (and probably @BugFinder also) is that you want `[0], [1], ... [9], [10], [2], [4]`. The only problem is that there are no criteria to make that sort possible.

Comment: @VDWWD yes correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the items at the indices and add them later.

```
        List<Department> departmentList = new List<Department>();
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 1, Description = "HR" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 2, Description = "IT" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 3, Description = "Sales" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 4, Description = "Accounting" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 5, Description = "Marketing" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 6, Description = "Fun" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 7, Description = "Games" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 8, Description = "Awesome" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 9, Description = "Confusing" });

        Department item4 = departmentList[3];
        Department item6 = departmentList[5];

        departmentList.Remove(item4);
        departmentList.Remove(item6);

        departmentList.Add(item4);
        departmentList.Add(item6);
```

And then bind the control.

Comment: Ok i m checking

Comment: Please review my updated question, I was trying similarly as u said but getting issue

Comment: What is the type that is being bound to the DataList? Is it a generic list or something else?

Comment: So, use List<Product>, not List<ProductDataSource>.

Comment: ok that is resolved now error is coming on var   foreach (var items in narrowsearchstoredata)
            {
                narrowsearch.Add(items);
            }

Comment: Ok i am getting

Comment: In your original code, what type is returned by ProductDataSource.NarrowSearch(_Keywords, this.CategoryId, _ManufacturerId, 1, 0, _PageSize, (_HiddenPageIndex * _PageSize), SortResults.SelectedValue)?

Comment: I was List<Product>